# Cannot do 'apt update' - IP address not found - no release file

Tags: networking, apt, updates

I am trying to install a package (make) on my Ubuntu 21.04 server.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

---

I get the following error messages:

```
$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:2 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
Err:5 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:6 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:7 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Err:8 http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 150.101.135.3 80]
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                          
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I get the same results for the "main" update server, and another Australian one (au.archive.ubuntu.com/).

So naturally installing "make" does not work:

```
$ sudo apt install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate
```

This weird because the same system successfully installed things a week or two ago, with no changes made to it.

---

This is my /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_ - Release amd64 (20210420)]/ hirsute main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe
# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner

deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ hirsute-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

---

Why would the IP address not be found? What am I doing wrong? Is there some mis-configuration somewhere?

I note that the Ubuntu directories seem to have been updated today (24 July 2022):

[image: Index of /pub/ubuntu/ubuntu/]

Would that be related?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: There have been no updates in ages  (*I do recall seeing EOL upgrade fix going thru [last night AEST local time] but didn't take notice; if you upgraded prior to EOL it wasn't an issue anyway*), and you've already missed your *release-upgrade* window too as [21.10 recently went EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/) and yes the EOL is a **huge** part of your issue(s).  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months as required by your 21.04 choice.

Comment: FYI:  Mirrors are free *drop* support anytime **after** the release reaches EOL, some are quick, others not so quick..

Comment: So I've missed an upgrade window? A month ago it would have worked and now it doesn't?

Comment: A few days ago it would have.. You can of course try, I sure would, and you may find some mirror(s) that haven't dropped it & you can force it via *hacks* (eg. the [Ubuntu Release Upgrade tool](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) checks https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release which now shows 21.10 is unsupported)... the change I saw related to that, but I took little interest in it & moved on...

Comment: Here's what currently seems to work for me to upgrade to 21.10 (upgrade in progress) `wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/impish-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/impish.tar.gz`, `tar xzvf impish.tar.gz`, `sudo ./impish`